# VirtualKey detect when is held down

Tags: c#, uwp

I am trying to get when you press the key that it continuous movement when a key is held down. But when press it move once and wait a second before it continues. I am using:

```
Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown += CoreWindow_KeyDownAsync;
```

and to get check in the method:

```
args.VirtualKey == Windows.System.VirtualKey.S;
```

Is there a way that it does not pause for that second, I just want to continues as long that key is held down.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot influence the speed by which the system reports the `KeyDown` event here, but you can subscribe to the `KeyUp` even too, and assume that key is pressed between the first time it is reported by `KeyDown` until a corresponding `KeyUp` occurs -

```
Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown += CoreWindow_KeyDown;
Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyUp += CoreWindow_KeyUp;
```

And the methods:

```
private void CoreWindow_KeyDown(
   Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow sender, 
   Windows.UI.Core.KeyEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.VirtualKey == Windows.System.VirtualKey.S)
    {
        //StartMoving(); (or keep moving if already started previously)
    }
}

private void CoreWindow_KeyUp(
   Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow sender, 
   Windows.UI.Core.KeyEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.VirtualKey == Windows.System.VirtualKey.S)
    {
        //StopMoving();
    }
}
```